# "Object.Key" search using map

Tags: javascript

I honestly have no idea how to explain this in the title, but I tried my best. What I want to do is grab all the objects/values from a string. However, since my objects can contain objects, I want to make sure that works as well. This is what I want to achieve:

```
var key = "House.Number";
var data = "...";
var output = data.map(item => item[key]);
```

What this should do, is give me all the house numbers. Simply doing `item["House.Number"]` won't work, but if I do `item["House"]["Number"]` it works just fine. Is there a quick/good way of doing this? Something like split on `.` means new object or something like that?

https://jsfiddle.net/psz4Ltqa/1/

Comment: Are you open to use any third-party library like lodash?

Comment: @31piy Unfortunately no. Vanilla JavaScript and/or jQuery.

Comment: The result when you do `item["House"]["Number"]` is just an array with numbers of houses? Is that what you want?

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen Yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split to a path and loop through the keys like so:

```js
var data = {
  One: {
    Two: {
      Three: 3
    }
  }
}

var getPath = function(obj, path) {
  return path
    .split(".") // Create an array of keys
    .reduce(function(pos, k) {
      return pos.hasOwnProperty(k) ? pos[k] : pos; // Return nested value or, if there isn't, last value
    }, obj);
}

console.log(getPath(data, "One.Two"));
console.log(getPath(data, "One.Two.Three"));
```

(Note that you can decide for your self what you want to do when paths are missing. You can for example return `undefined`, or like I chose to do, return the last value you could find)

Now, you can use this in a `map` operation like so:

```js
// Switched the argument order to make it more suitable for `map` (data last)
var getPath = function(path, obj) {
  return path
    .split(".") // Create an array of keys
    .reduce(function(pos, k) {
      return pos.hasOwnProperty(k) ? pos[k] : pos; // Return nested value or, if there isn't, last value
    }, obj);
};

var testData = [
  { One: { Two: { Three: "Three" } } },
  { One: { Two: { Three: 3 } } },
  { One: { Two: { Three: "11" } } }
];

var oneTwoThrees = testData.map(getPath.bind(null, "One.Two.Three"));

console.log(oneTwoThrees);
```

If you don't like the bind syntax, you can curry the function:

```js
// getPath now returns a function that wraps the path in its closure and waits for the object to get its data from
var getPath = function(path) {
  return function(obj) {
    return path
      .split(".") // Create an array of keys
      .reduce(function(pos, k) {
        return pos.hasOwnProperty(k) ? pos[k] : pos; // Return nested value or, if there isn't, last value
      }, obj);
  };
};

var testData = [
  { One: { Two: { Three: "Three" } } },
  { One: { Two: { Three: 3 } } },
  { One: { Two: { Three: "11" } } }
];

var oneTwoThrees = testData.map(getPath("One.Two.Three"));

console.log(oneTwoThrees);
```

Comment: Close. I want the equivalent of `item["House"]["Number"]` which returns the values.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Would you be able to tell me, if I can do something similar to `getPath()` which takes a 2nd argument as value? It would go something like this: `getPath("House.Number", 4)` which would return all the *houses* as objects, which have the number 4.

Comment: Certainly possible. Use `filter` and the `getPath` function to create your data set: https://jsfiddle.net/5y6cL5ez/

Comment: Hmm that's odd. I can get this to work with my own example and yours, but not in my application. http://i.imgur.com/e4oVBcL.png <-- That's how my data is structured. Array with 86 objects in it. Each object has a Stable which has a Number. `"Stable.Number"` is passed to `getPath` and then I filter it. I have tried `"3"` and `3` (string vs number) but it's the same deal. I just get an empty array.

Comment: I fixed it. Damn. I'm doing this with TypeScript, and it turns out that it was a number to string conversion error. I added `toString()` and now it works fine. Weird!

Answer (score 2):

According to your requirement:

> What this should do, is give me all the house numbers.

Simple solution using regular `for` loop and `String.prototype.split()` function:

```
...
var output = data.map(function(item){
    var path = key.split('.'), val = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = path.length; i < len; i++) {
        val = val[path[i]] || item[path[i]]; 
    }
    return val;
});

console.log(output); // all house numbers
```

The output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/psz4Ltqa/3/

Answer (score 1):

So basically you need this:

```
data.map(item => item["House"]["Number"])
```

But you want to achieve it with a given `key`. You can do this:

```
var keys = key.split('.'), output = data;

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    output = output.map(item => item[keys[i]]);
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this.
I am using this function in my project, and it works well.

```
  function nestedValue (obj, key) {
    var tmp = obj;
    var keys = key.split('.');
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length && tmp; i ++) 
      tmp = tmp[keys[i]];

    return tmp;
  }
```

then use this in map.

```
    var output = data.map(item => nestedValue(item, key));
```